# Why can I not post information on Weller WTCPN Soldering Iron repair process?

Tags: discussion

I was going to document my findings on Weller WTCPN repairs, part by part, but apparently I need  do something more first.

This seems to be rather limiting ad chases away contributors, IMO.

It's unclear why you do this.

Comment: This is a question-and-answer site, not a "document my findings" site.

Comment: This is a Q&A repository, postings must be framed as such

Comment: A quick hack (and an acceptable practice) is to write a proper question and self-answer it with your findings. But be prepared to get downvoted for both if it is not interesting or low quality.

Comment: You appear to have confused this site with a forum or redit. You're perfectly welcome to contribute, as long as you stick with the program - either ask a question, or post an answer to someone else's question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to contribute to?

Comment: Aha, now the site allows me to add a comment.  Until now it simply denied my ability to add **anything** and simply said "you need a "X" to comment/post..". This is progress.     Let me back up.  I read and benefited from a Q/A thread on repairing ancient weller WTCPNs. I attempted to add and improve it (documenting my testing, new failure modes, and suggested fixes). I was unable to for the above-mentioned reasons (whatever the points system is here, plus, from what i experience here, some site tech issues).  We shall see how my experience improves.

Comment: You can comment on your own posts, but not other's until you reach 50 reputation points. This is not a tech issue of the site, this is by design. Really, you should thoroughly read the help center topics to understand how this place works. It isn't complicated, but it is different from most other sites (and completely different from a regular forum), and if you don't make the effort to understand how it works, you will likely break some rules and have your posts removed (see what already happened).

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons.

First, this is a Q/A site.  All of the originating posts are questions, and then responders post answers.  Blog-formats are not what this site does.  This is common across dozens of different stack exchange sites.

Next, the repair of consumer electronics is simply off topic here, though well-founded questions about the electronics and debugging steps underlying a repair might be on-topic.

So, if during your repair, you encountered a non-obvious tricky step that required some electronics knowledge and technique to resolve, and you can phrase it as a question, post it, and then post your own answer underneath, as a response.

That's as best I can answer you without actually seeing the question you're trying to post, but I can't find it in your main user profile.

Lastly, you should take a peek at the site tour: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Stack exchanges mission is to build a high quality repository of questions with good answers.

You can contribute whatever you want, but your posts need to be in the form of a question and on topic.

Questions that are not on topic are closed, at that point they can be edited to make them on topic or deleted.

If you are simply posting information, this may not be the best place to do that.